# How to filter by id?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, filter

```
const allStories = [{id: 5, title: 'Hello title'}, {id: 10, title: 'Hello title2'}];
const id = ["5","25","10"];
const book = allStories.filter(story => story.story_id === id);
console.log(book)
```

**I want to filter stories by ids. I have tried to use .filter method but it is showing me empty array []**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few issues:

1. You're using `.story_id` when your object is  using `id`
2. You're trying to check if a number is equal to the array `id`, this won't work.

Instead, you can use [`.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes#Specifications) method on your array to check if your (string) id from the object is included within the `id` array like so:

```js
const allStories = [{id: 5, title: 'Hello title'}, {id: 10, title: 'Hello title2'}];
const id = ["5","25","10"];
const book = allStories.filter(story => id.includes(String(story.id)));
console.log(book)
```

If you want to remove the ids in the `id` array rather than keep them, you can negate the return value of `.includes()` using `!`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all what you were doing was comparing a string with the integer Object which may give horrible results. So for this make id array as an integer array. Also, for comparison you can use includes method. which can check if your id can exists at any index in the array. Like this

```
 const allStories = [{id: 5, title: 'Hello title'}, {id: 10, title: 'Hello 
 title2'}];
 const id = [5,25,10];
 const book = allStories.filter(story => id.includes(story.id));
 console.log(book)
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can use Following Script. Its Work For Me

```js
const allStories = [{
  id: 5,
  title: 'Hello title'
}, {
  id: 10,
  title: 'Hello title2'
}];
const id = ["5", "25", "10"];
let arr = allStories.filter(function(item) {
  return id.indexOf(item.id) === -1;
});
console.log(arr);
```